# Rust program, which reads, processes, and writes a file

Tags: performance, file, io, rust

I'm making a small program to benchmark Rust's performance compared to some other languages. The idea I came up with, was to take a file (with the numbers 1 to 10000000 written to it in separate lines) as a command line argument:

```
1
2
3
...
9999999
10000000
```

read the file, and then multiple every line in that file by two and write those back to the same file, so the end result would look like this:

```
2
4
6
...
19999998
20000000
```

My code works, and does exactly what it should do. I am especially looking for ways how I could make the code cleaner while also making it run faster. I'm currently running it with:

```
$ cargo run --release numbers.txt
```

The program:

```rust
use std::env;
use std::fs::OpenOptions;
use std::io::Read;
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let file_path = &args[1];

    let mut file = OpenOptions::new().read(true).open(file_path).unwrap();
    let mut contents = String::new();
    file.read_to_string(&mut contents).unwrap();
    let vec: Vec<i32> = contents.lines()
        .map(|line| line.trim().parse::<i32>().unwrap() * 2)
        .collect();

    let mut file = OpenOptions::new().write(true).open(file_path).unwrap();
    for line in vec {
        write!(file, "{}\n", line).unwrap();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my first post here, but I thought I might give this one a shot.

- Your code could be made more user friendly by providing custom error messages.

  - When you get the filename from the command line arguments, you assume that the user will provide at least one command line argument. You could provide a helpful error message if they don't.
  - If opening a file fails for some reason (probably that the file doesn't exist at all), you could provide a custom print-out.
  - My example uses `expect()` as an example, but in code where user-friendliness is actually a goal, you would probably want to use `eprintln!("error message here")` and `std::process::exit(1)` to quit the program. That way, you don't get rust's extra panic messages which a user shouldn't have to understand.
- You don't actually have to allocate a `Vec` to read the command line arguments, you can use the `.nth` method on the `Args` iterator.
- You don't need the `trim()` call, because the `lines()` iterator already removes the newlines.
- If you are looking to make the code cleaner, you could open the file for reading with `File::open`, and open it for writing with `File::create`.
- I don't know how to significantly improve the performance of your code.

  - The biggest thing that I notice is that when you write the processed sequence of numbers to the file, you call `write!` on every line. This means that you talk to the OS every time you write a number. This could be made faster by using BufWriter, which would let you talk to the file only once. Alternatively, you could construct your output string while you are *reading* the file.

```
use std::env;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufReader, BufRead};
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    let file_path = &env::args().nth(1).expect("must provide an input file");

    let file = File::open(file_path).expect("failed to open input file");

    let doubled_contents: String = BufReader::new(file).lines()
        .map(|line| {
            let number = line.unwrap().parse::<i32>().expect("failed to parse file");
            format!("{}\n", number*2)
        })
        .collect();

    let mut output_file = File::create(file_path).expect("failed to open output file");
    write!(output_file, "{}", doubled_contents).expect("could not write output");
}
```